# bootstrap validator with bootstrap select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with few input fields and select menus. I'm using bootstrap select plugin for select menus. [Link](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
So I just completed all things and applied bootstrap validation using this plugin. [Link](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator) and it's working fine **except select menus.**

When I click the select menu and click out side ( without selecting menu items ) It didn't do anything. Normally it should change border color and give error message like this. "Please fill out this field." But when I click submit, it working fine. After that I removed bootstrap selectpicker plugin. Then it worked fine. I'm thinking that there are conflicts with both two plugins. Please see example images.

**Click select menu and outside click(not working)**
[image]

**Click form submit and working fine.** 
[image]

And I tried with this code but no luck. I need to show an error message when someone click select menu and if he doesn't choose anything and click outside like input fields. What is the best solution for this?

Here is an example
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vixedijere/)

```
<form data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select" class="control-label">Title</label>
         <div class="form-input">
           <select class="selectpicker form-control" title="Please Select" id="select" name="select" required>
             <option value=""></option>
             <option value="1">Mr</option>
             <option value="2">Mrs</option>
             <option value="3">Ms</option>
             <option value="4">Miss</option>
             <option value="5">Dr</option>
           </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>

$('.select').on( 'hide.bs.select', function ( ) {
    $(this).trigger("focusout");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are handling the `hide.bs.select` event on the `select` class that is not on your select input. Try with `.selectpicker` instead :

```
<form data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select" class="control-label">Title</label>
         <div class="form-input">
           <select class="selectpicker form-control" title="Please Select" id="select" name="select" required>
             <option value=""></option>
             <option value="1">Mr</option>
             <option value="2">Mrs</option>
             <option value="3">Ms</option>
             <option value="4">Miss</option>
             <option value="5">Dr</option>
           </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>

$('.selectpicker').on( 'hide.bs.select', function ( ) {
    $(this).trigger("focusout");
});
```

Here is [the updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/seyukevake/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: But one thing, Seems it doesn't show "has-success" styles. Just apply form-control class but not working at all. Updated http://output.jsbin.com/saxitoxili

Comment: @MarkNsu I'm not sure to understand your comment. You did not talk about "has-success" in your question. The jsbin link does not work.

Comment: If someone filled out form, green color border apply for input field border.(has-success class) But it doesn't apply for select menus.  Here is the updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/saxitoxili

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ".selectpicker".

Maybe it will helps you to solve yout issue:

http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-select/

Comment: The link is broken: next time it's more useful if you provide some code as well :)